# Is there a simple way to know how many rows are in a wrapped Flexbox?

Tags: css, flexbox

**I want to color stripe each row inside a multi-row flexbox**

```
.container{ 
    display:flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
}
```

Has anyone discovered a simple way to determine the row count of a flexbox?

I looked at this question that did not accomplish the striping, but instead "manually" marks the Html element in order to stripe: [Zebra striping a flexbox table with wrapping items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35355253/zebra-striping-a-flexbox-table-with-wrapping-items)

I looked at this question which accomplishes the task by programmatically calculating the row-breaks in JavaScript. It counts the number of different `getBoundingClientRect` `.top` in the container: [zebra striping rows in a flex container with flex-wrap:wrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36730736/zebra-striping-rows-in-a-flex-container-with-flex-wrapwrap)

I don't mind the JS, but, unfortunately, this solution also requires watching for changes in both the page layout and the content of each wrapped item inside the container.

Does anyone have a solution that doesn't require "manually" monitoring the layout and content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering that [CSS has no way of knowing when an element wraps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37413580/3597276), a scripted solution is probably your best bet, *unless* the number of items per row is consistent throughout the container. Then you may be able to match individual items with [CSS **`nth-child`** pseudo-classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child), which could result in color-coded rows.

Answer (score 3):

```
 const calculateNumberOfRowsOfFlexBox = (children: any): number => {
   if (!children) {
      return -1
   }

   const items: any[] = Array.from(children)
   let baseOffset = items[0].offsetTop
   let numberOfRows = 0

   items.forEach(item => {
      if (item.offsetTop > baseOffset) {
         baseOffset = item.offsetTop
         numberOfRows += 1
      }
   })
   return numberOfRows
}

const numberOfRows = calculateNumberOfRowsOfFlexBox(containerRef?.current?.children)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: this is a pretty neat scripted solution. thank you.